# How to remove items from custom list-view without deleting it from mysql database?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, relational-database

I am a newbie in android programming. I am facing an issue related to listview. My requirement is that I want my list view to be filled with the content related to user's past feedbacks. But, I also have created a button for deleting the contents from user's wall. So, my question is how do I delete the contents from the user's wall and not from the database? Please help me out guys. I am stuck since past one hour.
Regards,
Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to answer this without knowing a lot more of how your app is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. Could you just suggest me some ways by which I can accomplish my task.

Comment: What I had done is, allow users submit their reviews and that data is stored onto my database and also I am able to display the user's feedback on the dedicated timeline. What I want now is just let user delete some of the past feedbacks in case his wall becomes a mess, but without deleting it from the database. !

Comment: you can add another table with the "deleted" feedback and exclude the deleted records from the query

Comment: Right, but I think that is not the solution. It is, but it adds one more table to my database.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryogurt Thanks man. Because of you I got a solution finally. Anybody facing the same issue just needs to create a column on their table isDeleted to check whether user has ever deleted contents or not. Set isDeleted to true if user ever clicked on delete button else it will be false. If isDeleted has true user has deleted the contents do not show him anything from the database. If its false allow him view the contents.